# Angular multiple transclude dynamic number of elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

Angular 1.5 enables the ability to [multi transclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude).

Notably, it'd be useful to be able to transclude a dynamic number of items into a directive and declare the names and locations of those transcludes at a later time (e.g. in the link/compile).

To further illustrate, I want the ability to do something like:

```
//Example usage of directive
<multi-slot-transclude-example>
<transclude1>TEST1</div>
<transclude2>TEST2</div>
<transclude3>TEST3</div>
<transclude4>TEST4</div>
.... dynamic number of items ...
</multi-slot-transclude-example>

//Example of directive that dynamically transcludes multiple items
angular.module("multiSlotTranscludeExample", [])
    .directive("directiveName", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: {
            't1': '?transclude1',
            't2': '?transclude2',
            //I'd like this list to be able to be defined non-statically (e.g. in link)
        },
        template: '<div ng-repeat="n in transcludedElementList">'
        + '<div ng-transclude="t{{n}"></div>'
        + '</div>'
        };
})
```

Note that in the directive declaration which implements a multi-transclude, I have to have prior knowledge about the number of items that will be transcluded when declaring it.

Is there a way to do something like this in either a link (or using a workaround), which would keep the same functionality that transclusion current offers?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Angular does not seem to provide any non-intrusive way to do this.

However, it can be achieved with a little tweak.

We need to intervene in angular.js's transclusion slot logic:

```js
...

var slots = createMap();

$template = jqLite(jqLiteClone(compileNode)).contents();

// Small tweak to allow dynamic transclusion
if (directiveValue === 'dynamic') {
  directiveValue = $parse(templateAttrs.transcludeDynamic)();
}

if (isObject(directiveValue)) {

  // We have transclusion slots,
  // collect them up, compile them and store their transclusion functions
  $template = [];

...
```

This allows us to specify the transclusion options in the component's consumer, like so:

```html
<my-custom-component transclude-dynamic="{testSlot: 'test', testSlot2: 'test2'}">
  <test>something to transclude</test>
  <test2>then another slot content to transclude</test2>
</my-custom-component>
```

In the component we enable dynamic transclusion:

```js
...
selector: 'myCustomComponent',
template: template,
transclude: 'dynamic',
bindings: {
  transcludeDynamic: '<'
}
```

Note that we also bind the transclusion info, this enables us to ng-repeat, ng-if and any other logic on it.

For example:

```html
<div ng-repeat="(slot, name) in $ctrl.transcludeDynamic">
  <div ng-transclude="{{slot}}"></div>
  <hr>
  <div>something else</div>
</div>
```

PR: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/14227